# How to optimize chunking of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I need to split my dataset into chunks, which i currently do with the following simple code:

```
    cases = []
    for i in set(df['key']):
        cases.append(df[df['key']==i].copy())
```

But my dataset is huge and this ends up taking a couple hours, so I was wondering if there is a way to maybe use multithreading to accelerate this? Or if there is any other method to make this go faster?

Comment: I really don't think you want to go down this path. I think you need to expand the question to incorporate the task you want to do in a broader sense (put the multiprocessing to one side for now)

Comment: what is *huge* ? rows ? columns ?

Comment: roughly 80 million rows by 30 columns, and some 30,000 unique keys I'm trying to split by

Comment: @AntoineBarthelet multiprocessing is a way to get around the GIL - pandas, or mostly numpy, can do that naturally. It sounds like you have a good pandas question. I reiterate that I think the multiprocessing approach should be dropped and you should let people scrutinise the code you're trying to speed up (in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you want to group-by unique keys. Use the built-in functionality to do this.

```
cases = list(df.groupby('key'))
```

Comment: This should be the right answer if the data fits into memory.